# Deixar duas Divs sempre com a mesma height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou utilizando o bootstrap, já tentei utilizar o `display:table-cell` e `display:cell` nas `divs` filhos, porém, nada funcionou, tenho duas `divs`, e as duas têm conteúdo dinâmico, porém preciso que as duas sempre fiquem do mesmo tamanho.

```
<div class='row'>
 <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-5'>
  CONTEUDO 1
 </div>
 <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-7'>
  CONTEUDO 2
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Eu sei fazer isso usando [Flexbox](http://tableless.com.br/flexbox-organizando-seu-layout/), mas tenho quase certeza que isso inviabilizaria seu uso com as classes personalizadas do Bootstrap... Suas divs têm altura previsível, ou ela é variável?

Comment: completamente variáveis.

Comment: Não acho que seja duplicata porque neste caso é com Bootstrap.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Encontrei uma solução nesse artigo (em inglês): ["Bootstrap 3 responsive columns of same height"](http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-columns-of-same-height). Ele cria um conjunto de classes para garantir que todas as colunas em uma linha tenham a mesma altura. As que te interessam nesse caso são:

```
.row-same-height {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  /* fix overflow */
  table-layout: fixed;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-height {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none !important;
  }
}
```

(há outras para as demais resoluções - `xs`, `md` e `lg` - bem como outras que te dão diferentes tipos de controle)

Exemplo:

```css
.row div {
    border: 1px solid black; // Para visualização; não usar na prática
}

.row-same-height {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  /* fix overflow */
  table-layout: fixed;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-height {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='container'>
<div class='row row-same-height'>
 <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-sm-height' contentEditable="true">
     <p>CONTEUDO 1</p>
     <p>CONTEUDO 1</p>
     <p>CONTEUDO 1</p>
     <p>CONTEUDO 1</p>
     <p>CONTEUDO 1</p>
     <p>CONTEUDO 1</p>
     <p>CONTEUDO 1</p>
     <p>CONTEUDO 1</p>
     <p>CONTEUDO 1</p>
     <p>CONTEUDO 1</p>
     <p>CONTEUDO 1</p>
     <p>CONTEUDO 1</p>
 </div>
 <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-sm-height' contentEditable="true">
  CONTEUDO 2
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Veja o exemplo em "Página toda", para ver o efeito. Coloquei as `div`s com `contentEditable` para você poder editá-las e ver como o conteúdo se adapta à altura da maior coluna, além de uma borda para auxiliar na visualização, esses artifícios não devem estar presentes no código real.

Answer (score -1):

No bootstrap você não é necessariamente obrigado a apenas utilizá-lo. Você pode personalizá-lo. E uma maneira de resolver seu problema é: Adicione uma nova classe em ambas as divs e em seguida crie um estilo para tal classe:

NO HTML:

```
<div class='row'>
 <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-5 minha-classe'>
  CONTEUDO 1
 </div>
 <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-7 minha-classe'>
  CONTEUDO 2
 </div>
</div>
```

E o CSS:

```
.minha-classe { min-height: 100px; height:150px; max-height:200px; } /* altura mínima de 100px, altura normal de 150px altura máxima de 200px*/
```

Comment: mas ambas tem conteudo dinamico, uma hora uma está 1300px e a outra esta 10px por exemplo

Comment: Nesse caso você determina o min-height. Vou editar a resposta pra você ver.

Comment: ja utilizei tambem, não funciona, o que eu preciso é necessariamente deixar ambas na mesma altura de height, exatamente iguais.